# jquery superbox library not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Hello i am testing out the jquery superbox library. I have the following example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.superbox-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.superbox.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.superbox.css">

<script>
$(function(){
    $.superbox();
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>


<a href="#box-content" rel="superbox[content]">SuperBox</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when i click the link nothing happens. Anyone know why it wouldn't work?

Comment: you don't need to import jquery.superbox twice - you are importing both the compressed and uncompressed version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the console log, you will see the error that: `TypeError: i.browser is undefined`

As the plugin is an old one, and you are trying with jQuery 2.1.1, you are getting that error because within the plugin's source code, [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) feature, which has been removed after jQuery 1.9, is being used.

Also you don't have any element with the id `box-content`. So add that to your html too.

For working example, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxe89/

Comment: now its working perfect.Thanks so much!! hey how would i be able to load an external page within that superbox? can i do something like this? <a href="externalPage.php" rel="superbox[content]">SuperBox</a>

Comment: welcome, i guess it needs absolute path i haven't tried in local actually, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxe89/1/